# Python ldap3 search creates an empty entry

Tags: python, search, filter, ldap

The first step of my program requires I search through the company's active directory and find a list of users by department. Here is my code so far:

```
from ldap3 import Server, Connection, SUBTREE, ALL
server = Server('my.company.local', get_info=ALL)
conn = Connection(server, auto_bind=True)
conn.search('dc=my, dc=company, dc=local', '(givenName=Charles)')
print(conn.entries)
```

However, no matter what I put in the search filter part of conn.search, no data is found in my entries log. The entries log is an empty list. When I pull up Active Directory Users and Computer, I can go through each department and find names and search their attribute editor (and yes there is a GivenName=Charles in there). Please point me in the right direction as to why there's no data returned as I'm running out of ideas. Thanks.

EDIT: If it's relevant, print(server.schema) returns None. Also, print(conn) returns as `insert my.company.local here:389 - cleartext - user: None - not lazy - bound - open - <local: 10.5.112.213:63755 - remote: 10.5.107.41:389> - tls not started - listening - SyncStrategy - internal decoder`
Which makes me pretty certain I'm connected.

Comment: No errors? Are you sure you are connecting? Does the `conn` have any other interesting methods that might help you check your connection? "We prefer questions that can be answered, not just discussed. Provide details. Share your research."

Comment: You don't seem to be supplying any credentials to AD. `ldap3`, unlike the ADUC control, doesn't seem to automatically inherit your user token. Hence, you've performed an anonymous bind to AD which, while it succeeds, doesn't provide you with a context in which you can run searches, etc. Basically, you need to somehow provide credentials in order to be able to search.

Answer (score 2):

So both cannatag and ig0774 were correct. Providing user credentials is necessary to use the search function. Otherwise the search function returns an empty entries list. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Shot in the dark, but try removing the parentheses around the query so `(givenName=Charles)` becomes `givenName=Charles`. Are you sure the domain components are correct?

Comment: The parenthesis are necessary. I just checked. I am 90% certain that my domain components are correct, as my Active Directory Users and Computers shows the same domain that I've put down in my code.

Comment: @Crazysexman: Ok, like I said it was just a shot in the dark.  Have you tried something that you know will return a result like `(cn=*)`?

Comment: Unfortunately yes, I have. I think I may be searching the wrong domain somehow but I don't know what's wrong exactly.

Comment: so if you do a `ldapsearch -H ldap://my.company.local:389 -x -b dc=my, dc=company, dc=local '(givenName=Charles)'` does it give the expected result?

Answer (score 1):

you are not providing a username, so your connection is anonymous. Try accessing with `username="myname", password="mypassword"` in the connection object. You can also try NTLM authentication with `authentication=NTLM`. (You must import NTLM from the ldap3 package). In this case username must be `"mydomain//myname"`.